# Is there some way to create a filter with more than one value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am fairly new to MongoDB and I am trying to create a filter that combines more than 1 property.

For example, let us say that I want to filter the search results based on whether the multiplication of two properties `a` and `b` from model `Object` is more than `threshold`.

Would I do something like this?

```js
Object.find({
   a * b : {$gt: threshold}
});
```

I have tried this, but I am getting all sorts of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the expression operator `$expr` to put condition for internal fields,

- do multiplication by `$multiply` operator
- `$gt` operator to match with `threshold` field

```
Object.find({
  $expr: {
    $gt: [
      { $multiply: ["$a", "$b"] },
      "$threshold"
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ts3iXaahQrk)